# SUMIFS on Google Apps Script using data on external sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to use this marketing campaign data on the "Raw Data" Sheet here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/137Z89OXT-9RfCR95C6_vdoBKNh5MfRsWApivdO0CMcE/edit?usp=sharing

There will be multiple criteria fields but use any 2 to illustrate

Then print the sum of each of the last 5 fields onto "Destination" sheet in a new row-- below corresponding field names here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i9HUCkXrNHX4iqMEXKApqE_zKjrAIFA-3H9ZIo73OTc/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Pls, share a file instead of images. People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you. You can always create a sheet of dummy data that people can access and play with. By doing so, people will be more eager to help out.;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I built this basic pivot table in your sheet, will that work?
[image]

Comment: Thank Dmitry. However, I actually need to cycle through multiple "Raw Data" sheets every week. The "Destination" sheet will be a summary of these different campaign data sheets. Not sure if a pivot can capture all of that automatically, but let me know if this is possible.

Comment: You can use multiple `IMPORTRANGE()` statements to consolidate your raw data sheets and then build a pivot from the consolidated data

Comment: Sure, just leave a comment if you need help with that